# how to make same chart with lightweight chart with javascript

Tags: javascript, charts, lightweight-charts

[image: bitmex example image show click]

I am use https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts javascript package.

As you can see in the picture, orders are shown in green boxes on the bitmex exchange. I want to learn how I can do this in my own table. I could not find a similar example in the document. Can you help me ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it couldn't be done with `lightweight-charts`. If you'd like to add them and want to use TradingView's charts, I'd suggest you take [charting library](https://www.tradingview.com/HTML5-stock-forex-bitcoin-charting-library/?feature=technical-analysis-charts) instead.

Comment: Hi. Do you know of any way to access the Chartling Library if you are not a company? Thanks